# Un legend en mi Barplot

Tags: r, script

Estimada comunidad, el inconveniente que tengo el día de hoy es que quisiera hacer que la legend de mi barplot no me tape el gráfico y como agregarle mas detalle para que mejore la presentación.

Gracias por su presencia

```
datos = c(21,22,22,8,25,31,16,15)
length(datos)
data_juegos = matrix(datos, nrow = 2, ncol = 4, byrow = T,
                 dimnames = list(c("Es extranjero", "No es extranjero"), 
                                 c("De 15 a 20", "De 20 a 25", "De 25 a 30", 
                                   "De 30 o mas")))
barplot(data_juegos, main = "Localidad de los jugadores", xlab = "Edades", 
    col = c("chartreuse4", "darkorchid4"), density = 300, angle = c(135, 45), 
    legend = rownames(data_juegos))
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

la función bar plot tiene un argumento para que puedas mover de forma por decirlo manual a posición de la legenda el "args.legend", lo que quedaría así

```
datos = c(21,22,22,8,25,31,16,15)
length(datos)
data_juegos = matrix(datos, nrow = 2, ncol = 4, byrow = T,
                 dimnames = list(c("Es extranjero", "No es extranjero"), 
                                 c("De 15 a 20", "De 20 a 25", "De 25 a 30", 
                                   "De 30 o mas")))
barplot(data_juegos, main = "Localidad de los jugadores", xlab = "Edades", 
    col = c("chartreuse4", "darkorchid4"), density = 300, angle = c(135, 45),
    legend.text = TRUE, #con este código ya no es necesario agregar manualmente el texto de las columnas
    args.legend=list(
      legend=rownames(data_juegos), 
      x=ncol(data_juegos)+1,        #Este es el argumento que tienes que modificar el eje x
      y=max(colSums(data_juegos))+3 #Este es el argumento que tienes que modificar el eje x
      ))
```

En este ejemplo utilizo ncol(data_juegos) para mencionar que la etiqueta debe estar a la izquierda de la ultima columna para evitar que lo tape, y max(colSums(data_juegos))+3 es para que la grafica aparezca mas arriba de la barra mas alta, al final puede jugar con los valores hsta que exista uno que te funcione